# Receiving messages from WSO2 Message Broker with Process Server

Tags: jms, wso2, server

I successfully configured WSO2 Message Broker as a JMS server. I have configured WSO2 ESB to send messages to a queue, and I can see this queue get created in MB with messages.

Now, I want to consume those messages with Process Server and kick off a BPEL process. I have added the required libraries to components/lib in both ESB and BPS, and have created an identical jndi.properties in both. The URL for both ESB and BPEL is:

```
jms:/newMLECaseQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue
```

I have tested a similar configuration with ActiveMQ, and there BPEL succesfully picked up the messages. In MB it does not seem to work, while the logging mentions that JMS started to listen:

```
Started to listen on destination : newMLECaseQueue of type queue for service newMLECaseQueue {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener}
```

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that each queue must be registered using jndi.properties: when adding the queue with the line:

```
queue.newMLECaseQueue = newMLECaseQueue
```

it all started to work.